# Standard tourist visa bank statements for couples

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

My wife and I have a biometric scheduled for a UK visitor visa later this month. At this moment, I have an important question about the bank statements that I need to send with my application. Because of some personal reasons my balance for the last 6 months hovers around $3k-$5k and my wife's account is in pretty good standing. Since we have two separate applications, do we need to send bank statements for both of us, or is just one of us enough?

I saw this https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents in the website, which says we need not submit duplicate documents on both of our files. But I am not sure what I should infer with respect to bank statements.

Any help or advice is greatly welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Your bank statements are in your name only? Or in both of your names?

Comment: @Roddy It's only on my name. We both have separate accounts.

Comment: Then submit both statements. How are they duplicates? They are not.  What that guideline means is that don’t submit the same bank statement 2 times because 2 people are going.

Comment: @HankyPanky with whose application should they submit the statements, and how should they maximize the chance that the wife's adequate balance will outweigh the husband's low balance?

Comment: @phoog I'm afraid its now too late to alter impact of each account on the application, because they have both completed the online application step and have already answered the questions about who holds how much and who will pay how much towards whose expenses on the trip. However both bank statements will be submitted together and will be available for both applications as all the documents of both (interlinked) applications go to the embassy in one packet, like a joint application. Both printed applications, all the supporting documents will be in 1 packet

Answer (score 1):

> Since we have two separate applications, do we need to send bank statements for both of us, or is just one of us enough?

You and your wife applied individually, as required, and will transmit your applications together. The [UK supporting documents guidance](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf) notes that those applying as a family/group you *do not need to provide multiple copies of the **same documents**.*

However, as you note, you and your wife have *separate* financial records and, thus, they are not the same and *both* should be submitted, supporting the information provided in each application (and as cross-referenced in the UKVI system).